# Jquery Queue requests integration once First Request Success and then call the next request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, queue

Is there any way to integration Jquery Queue requests handling Once first request got the Success response then call the next request.

FYI I've used ajaxManager as below code but it is not waiting for previous request success response.

```
$(function() {
    ajaxManager.run();
    for (key in Reports) {
        var Url = Reports[key];
        if ( Url != '' ) {
            sendRequest(Url, key);
        }
    }
});

function sendRequest(Url, act_id) {
    ajaxManager.addReq({
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        url: Url,
        type: "POST",
        data: {},
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function(response) {
           console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Is there any other way which can handle this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how you can do this (i saved the reports in an array)

```
var reports = [11, 12, 14, 15];
function doTheReport() {
    if (reports.length === 0) {
        alert('All reports are done now.');
        return;
    }

    var report_Id = reports.pop();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/DoTheReport",
        complete: function () {
            doTheReport();
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing [jQuery.queue()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.queue/) , [jQuery.dequeue()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.dequeue/) ,

Try

```
$(function () {
    // requests url and data objects
    var Reports = [{
        "url": "url1",
        "data": JSON.stringify([1])
    }, {
        "url": "url2",
        "data": JSON.stringify([2])
    }, {
        "url": "url3",
        "data": JSON.stringify([3])
    }];
    // all responses
    var responses = [];
    // jQuery.deferred , resolved when all requests completed
    var requests = new $.Deferred() || $(requests);
    // do stuff when all requests completed
    requests.done(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert(data.length + " requests completed");
        $.each(data, function (k, v) {
            $("#results").append(v + "\n")
        })
    });
    // `request` fn
    var request = function (url, data) {
        return $.post(url, {
            json: data
        }, "json")
    };
    // `response` fn
    var response = function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        // if response `textStatus` === `success` , do stuff
        if (textStatus === "success") {
            console.log(data, textStatus);
            responses.push([textStatus, data, $.now()]);
            // if items in queue , dequeue next item
            if ($.queue(requests, "ajax").length) {
                $.dequeue(requests, "ajax")
            } else {
                // if items not in queue , resolve requests
                requests.resolve(responses)
            }
        };
    };
    // `error` fn
    // var error = function() {};
    // create queue of `request` functions
    $.each(Reports, function (k, v) {
        $.queue(requests, "ajax", function () {
            return request(v.url, v.data)
            .then(response /* , error */ )
        })
    });
        // dequeue first item in queue
        $.dequeue(requests, "ajax")
})
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/mgqhzejh/